# Service to Activity in Android

Tags: android, service, android-activity, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

How can I send data from a Service to an Activity?  Broadcast receiver?  Handlers? Intent? I have several `Strings` in particular that I would like to send from Service to an Activity, so that I can then display some View to the user.

`getApplication().startActivity(new Intent())`  ?

Comment: I did some more reading and I'm thinking about using Handler.  If I define my custom Handler in the Receiving class (to get the data), then I can just send messages from the Service class, right?

Answer (score 0):

Since both Activity & Service is in same application. Instead of going for Service Binder IPC, try implementing register callBack mechanism. Try follow below step.
 -> Make a static class which extends from class Application to make quick reference anywhere in your application. 
 -> Register a callBack from Activity to this application class.
 -> Post event from your service to the application class and let Application class deliver the event to all register callBacks.

Answer (score 0):

As @justin-shield mentioned the best way is to use some form of IPC.  I don't think you need to use AIDL, however.  You can see another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592178/android-service-notify-activity-completed-best-way/6592308#6592308) I gave to a similar question that outlines the basic steps to register Handlers and Messengers in your `Activity` and your `Service`.

Answer (score 0):

I think all your answers are way more complex than what I need.  I think I have come up with a rather simple solution (psuedo-code):

Service:

`Intent i = new Intent(this,Activity.class);`

`i.putExtra(name,value);`

`startActivity(i);`

Activty:

`private Intent intent;`

`private String s1;`

from the

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super(savedInstanceState);
```

`intent = this.getIntent(); //Gets the intent that started this Activity.    

s1=intent.getExtras().getString(name);`

}

Would I use same code in onStart() ?  What about onResume() ? onRestart() ?  Lastly, I only want to send to the Activity some data to publish via some View objects, I don't need any communication going back to the Service.