# Trying to keep my android multi-threaded FIle Observer Foreground Service alive

Tags: android, foreground-service, fileobserver

First of all, Thank you so much for reading this.
Currently, I am trying to build an Android App which monitors entire filesystem activity.
Therefore, I am implementing code from this link 
[Backgroundservice is running, but not working (FileObserver)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963951/backgroundservice-is-running-but-not-working-fileobserver)

Although I have managed to create foreground service which automatically starts on boot,
It does not last forever.

Problem is that I "NEED" this service to work and report entire filesystem activity constantly.

So, Please I beg of anyone who can help me.

I attach code below. Hope any wise man can tell me the solution...

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter; 
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.FileObserver;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class FileSystemObserverService extends Service {
String externalPath = "";
String internalPath = "";

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    observe();
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        final String strId = getString(R.string.noti_channel_id);
        final String strTitle = getString(R.string.app_name);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        NotificationChannel channel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(strId);
        if (channel == null) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(strId, strTitle, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, strId).build();
        startForeground(1, notification);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        stopForeground(true);
    } else {
        stopSelf();
    }
}

public File getInternalStoragePath() {
    File parent = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getParentFile();
    File external = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File[] files = parent.listFiles();
    File internal = null;
    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            if (files[i].getName().toLowerCase().startsWith("sdcard") && !files[i].equals(external)) {
                internal = files[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return internal;
}

public File getExtenerStoragePath() {
    return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
}

public void observe() {
    Thread t;
    t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            //File[]    listOfFiles = new File(path).listFiles();
            File str = getInternalStoragePath();
            if (str != null) {
                internalPath = str.getAbsolutePath();
                new Obsever(internalPath).startWatching();
            }
            str = getExtenerStoragePath();
            if (str != null) {
                externalPath = str.getAbsolutePath();
                new Obsever(externalPath).startWatching();
            }
        }
    });
    t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
    t.start();
}

class Obsever extends FileObserver {

    List<SingleFileObserver> mObservers;
    String mPath;
    int mMask;

    public Obsever(String path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this(path, ALL_EVENTS);
    }

    public Obsever(String path, int mask) {
        super(path, mask);
        mPath = path;
        mMask = mask;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void startWatching() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mObservers != null)
            return;
        mObservers = new ArrayList<SingleFileObserver>();
        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();
        stack.push(mPath);
        while (!stack.empty()) {
            String parent = stack.pop();
            mObservers.add(new SingleFileObserver(parent, mMask));
            File path = new File(parent);
            File[] files = path.listFiles();
            if (files == null) continue;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
                if (files[i].isDirectory() && !files[i].getName().equals(".") && !files[i].getName().equals("..")) {
                    stack.push(files[i].getPath());
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < mObservers.size(); i++) {
            mObservers.get(i).startWatching();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void stopWatching() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (mObservers == null)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; i < mObservers.size(); ++i) {
            mObservers.get(i).stopWatching();
        }
        mObservers.clear();
        mObservers = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, final String path) {
        if (event == FileObserver.OPEN) {
            writeLog("OPEN",path);
        } else if (event == FileObserver.CREATE && (!path.equals(".probe"))) {
            writeLog("CREATE",path);
        } else if (event == FileObserver.DELETE_SELF || event == FileObserver.DELETE) {
            writeLog("DELETE",path);
        } else if (event == FileObserver.MOVE_SELF || event == FileObserver.MOVED_FROM || event == FileObserver.MOVED_TO) {
            writeLog("MOVE",path);
        }
    }

    private class SingleFileObserver extends FileObserver {
        private String mPath;

        public SingleFileObserver(String path, int mask) {
            super(path, mask);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mPath = path;
        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String newPath = mPath + "/" + path;
            Obsever.this.onEvent(event, newPath);
        }

    }

}

public void writeLog(final String event, final String path){
    String filename = getFilesDir().toString()+"/log.txt";
    String to_write = event+" "+path+"\n";
    try{
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename, true));
        bw.write(to_write);
        bw.close();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.i("onEvent","Exception Error");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This will not work on Android 10 and higher, as you no longer have access to most of the filesystem. So, perhaps you should consider doing something else.

Comment: don't worry I figured it out by myself

Comment: If you have solved then please post an answer and mark it accepted.