# What is the difference between WatchService and FileObserver

Tags: java, android

what is the difference between both , which to use when any idea and which is the best to keep track of a directory change like delete file moved file?

Comment: Well, WatchService doesn't exist until API version 26.  So using it on the vast majority of ANdroid devices won't work.

Answer (score 0):

FileObserver is Android based while WatchService is Java based. You can use WatchService in Android as well since Android is a robust package of Java. Just as Java Serializable is to Android Parcellable, so is WatchService is to FileObserver.
I bet you, Android implementation works best as speed, efficiency and memory consciousness are better taken into account in Android

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am trying to update the recyclerview if the file is deleted or moved from the apps directory. Should i use fileobserver

Comment: You can find the best answer here http://automagic4android.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6937

Comment: i want to track the directory 24*7 any idea

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034748/how-to-monitor-folder-for-file-changes-in-background