# What is the correct intentfilter for a broadcast receiver to get media changes on external storage?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, action, intentfilter, android-external-storage

I just found

> ACTION_MEDIA_REMOVED

and am searching for something like:

> ACTION_MEDIA_INSERTED and ACTION_MEDIA_CHANGED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FileObserver` to observe for any change in a file or directory. Example usage.

Add the following permission in your manifest file

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

```
public class MyFileObserver extends FileObserver {

    String absolutePath = "path to your directory";

    public MyFileObserver(String path) {
        super(path, FileObserver.CREATE);
        absolutePath = path;
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(int event, String path) {
        // this is where you will receive all event like file modified, file added...
        if (path != null) {
            Log.e("File created..");
        }
    }
}
```

and in your activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MyFileObserver myFileObserver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myFileObserver = new DirectoryFileObserver("Path of the directory");
        myFileObserver.startWatching();
    }
}
```

and if you want to observe external storage in the background, then refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48238804/1749223)